# Getting error "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" when going from a custom Tabbar view to full screen and back

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, tabbar

I have the following observable objects:

```
class DisplayDetails: ObservableObject {

    @Published var showFullScreen: Bool = false

}


class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentView = "social"

}
```

Then this is the main view where the tab bar is displayed at start up:

```
struct AppView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()

    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails

    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
    
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                if self.viewRouter.currentView == "social" {
                    
                    Social()
                    
                } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "menu" {
                    
                    Menu()
                    
                }
        
            }
        
    
            // *** HERE IS WHERE I DO THE CHECK FOR FULL SCREEN OR TAB BAR VIEW ***
            if (!displayDetails.showFullScreen) {
                      
                VStack {
                        
                    Spacer()
            
                    ZStack {
            
                        HStack {
                        
                            Button(action: {
                        
                                if (self.viewRouter.currentView != "social") {
                        
                                    self.viewRouter.currentView = "social"
                        
                                }
                        
                            }) {
                                
                                Image("Social")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            
                           }
                           .foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "socail" ? .black : .gray)

                           Spacer(minLength: 12)
                       
                           Button(action: {
                          
                               if (self.viewRouter.currentView != "menu") {
                            
                                   self.viewRouter.currentView = "menu"
                        
                               }
                        
                           }) {
                          
                               Image("Menu")
                                   .resizable()
                                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                   .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        
                          }
                          .foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "menu" ? .black : .gray)

                      }
                      .padding()
                      .padding(.horizontal, 22)
                      .background(CurvedShape())
                
                  }
                  .background(Color("Color")
                  .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
              
              }

          }
          
     }
      
}
```

By default the social tab bar is selected as seen in the ViewRouter

The view for that is as follows:

```
struct Social: View {

    // Used to track for full display
    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            List {
                  
                ForEach(self.socialStore.social, id: \.self) { social in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SocialDetails()) {
                        
                        SocialCell(social: social)
                        
                    }
                }
            
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Social"))
            .padding(.bottom)
            .onAppear() {

                self.fetchsocial() // Firebase DB call to populate the list

            }

        }
        .padding(.bottom)

    }

}
```

Lastly, the Social Details Page which should be full screen and not include the tab bar:

```
struct SocialDetails: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails


    var body: some View {

        VStack {
    
            Image("image_here" )
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(150)
                .shadow(radius: 3)
        
            Text("User name")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
        
            Form {
        
                Section {
            
                    HStack {
                
                        Text("Phone")
                    
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("1234567890")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.callout)
                
                    }
                
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("Email")
                    
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("sg@sg.com" /*contact.email*/)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.callout)
                
                    }
                
                    HStack {
                
                        Text("Address")
                    
                        Spacer()
                    
                        Text("123 AVE" /*contact.address*/)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.callout)
                            .frame(width: 180)
                
                    }
                    
                }
        
            }
    
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()

            
        }
        .onDisappear {

            self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()
        
        }
    
    }

}
```

So when the app runs everything works fine, im able to navigate back and forth between tabs.
when I click an item in the Social tab list, the list rolls up vs just sliding to the right, which I assume that is happening as the view is "hiding" the tab bar for the detailed view.

Then on the back link to return to the list gets really funky.... and this is when the <<"Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior">> get seen.

What happens is really weird. The list actually displays but for about a second and then it rolls up again and the list is empty!?

The only good thing is that the tab bar is visible again as desired... but im assuming that the hiding and making visible is throwing the warning and as it suggests it is giving me undefined behavior!!!

Has anyone encountered this issue and were you able to resolve?

List must be from a dynamic source, in my instance its Firebase Realtime Database.

*** UPDATE:

Including video with issue with behavior:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2655vdrjb796d8o/test.mov?dl=0

Looking at the video, the list appears. When I click on an item in the list it navigates to the detailed view and hides the tab bar as desired. **Notice as it starts the navigation transition to the detailed view the list view rolls up the items in the list (which is weird)?? I expected just a slide to the detailed view. When I return the list is displayed (its like its unrolling from the first item in the list) and then the list rolls back up again into the first item and the screen ends up blank!?

UPDATE:

Below is my fetch function to get the data from Firebase Realtime Database, I am not sure if it is correct:

```
func fetch (userId: String) {
    
    ref.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
        for child in snapshot.children {
                
            if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                
                let review = Review(snapshot: snapshot) {
                    
                    self.reviews.append(review)
                
                }
                
        }

    })
            
}
```

Comment: I could not make this code do what you've described. Would you elaborate more on make it reproducible?

Comment: @Asperi can you comment on what you are experiencing as behavior?

Comment: @Asperi you will likely have to use a list that is from a dynamic source and not a static source like an array to see the behavior.

Comment: @Asperi were you able to recreate!?

Comment: No, provided code is not testable... try to copy-paste it as-is in new project.

Comment: Ok, I've managed this to work, but I do not observe run-time error you reported. Tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14. (I simulated list loaded dynamically)

Comment: @Asperi here is the video: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/2655vdrjb796d8o/test.mov?dl=0` Just looking at the video, the list appears. When I click on an item in the list it navigates to the detailed view and hides the tab bar as desired. But also notice as it starts the navigation transition the list view rolls up the items in the list (which is weird) I expected just a slide. When I return the list is displayed (its like its unrolling from the first item in the list) and then the list rolls up again and the screen ends up blank!? Do you have the same experience!?

Comment: Lastly, if I do not add the line of code `if (!displayDetails.showFullScreen) {` to hide the tabbar , the transition works fine as well as the navigation back to the list view... but the issue there is that I have a tabbar in the detailed view which is not wanted.

Comment: @Asperi i have added my swiftui code for the fetch function to get the data from firebase. Can you please validate if the code is valid?!

Comment: @Asperi can you please share your code, where you are saying you are not getting the issue and instead are getting the desired result?

Comment: @Asperi I have Xcode 11.6 (11E708)... do you think Apple resolved this "issue" with Xcode 12?!